Including a Suppression List in your API Call for MobileConnect
I want to be able to send an SMS via API in MobileConnect. However, I want to include a suppression list. I see how you can do this via JourneyBuilder or Scheduled send, but not via API. Would I just need to include the Suppression List in my json? Something like -
{
"To": {
"ContactKey": "12345",
"SubscriberKey": "12345",
"Address": "+15555555555"
},
"MessageText": "Your message content here.",
"Options": {
"SuppressList": ["SMS_Suppression_List"]
}
}
